Emulate std::start_lifetime_as_array in C++20
According to cppreference, no compiler currently supports std::start_lifetime_as_array.
However, a SO answer suggests that it can be "emulated" in C++20 as follows:
template<class T>
requires (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T>)
T* start_lifetime_as(void* p) noexcept
{
    return std::launder(static_cast<T*>(std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T))));
}

How can we similarly emulate std::start_lifetime_as_array without invoking undefined behaviour?
cppreference says that
template< class T >
T* start_lifetime_as_array( void* p, std::size_t n ) noexcept;


Implicitly creates an array with element type T and length n. To be precise, if n > 0 is true, it is equivalent to std::start_lifetime_as<U>(p) where U is the type "array of n Ts".

But n is only known at runtime.

It's unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate the qyestion?

@3CxEZiVlQ They have an implementation of start_lifetime_as.  They want to know if there is a way to adapt it to become start_lifetime_as_array

Context: That implementation was taken from a Stack Overflow answer

Your posted emulation is for start_lifetime_as but the surrounding text implies it's start_lifetime_as_array.  Could you edit to make it a little more clear?

@Craig Yes, they gave an example for an adjacent problem.  I found it clear enough that I found your question confusing.

Something like this based on your given example:
template<class T>
requires (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T>)
T* start_lifetime_as_array(void* p, std::size_t n) noexcept
{
    if(n == 0)
        return static_cast<T*>(p);
    else
        return std::launder(static_cast<T*>(std::memmove(p, p, sizeof(T)*n)));
}

However, neither std::start_lifetime_as that you show nor the function presented above are exactly conforming to their specification in the standard. For example:

There are missing overloads for all combinations of const/volatile qualifications on the pointers.

If T is incomplete, the call should be ill-formed. That isn't tested yet and must be tested in such a way that the requires clause is not otherwise evaluated, because the type traits cause undefined behavior if T is incomplete.

std::is_implicit_lifetime_v<T> is C++23, not C++20, and there is no way to implement it in C++20

std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> is not actually required. However, if it is not fulfilled, then some subobjects may have unspecified or indeterminate value after the call. If nested objects are not of implicit-lifetime type, then they do not have their lifetime started by std::start_lifetime_as.

Also, using a requires clause is technically incorrect. It should instead be a static_assert in the body. Otherwise it may be possible that overload resolution chooses a different overload with the same name, but that must not happen.

The standard guarantees that std::start_lifetime_as and std::start_lifetime_as_array will not actually access the memory/objects. However, memmove does do so. There is no way to provide this guarantee with user code.


